# Mongoose populate() returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a chat with node.js, Express & MongoDB. I have two mongoose models: for chat room and message.

Room model:

```
const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true,
    },

    messages: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Messages',
        required: true,
    },
    users: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true,
    },


});

const Room = mongoose.model('Rooms', RoomSchema);
```

Message model:

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sendBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

const Messages = mongoose.model('Messages', MessageSchema);
```

and a function for displaying all messages

```
prepareMessages: function (name, callback) {
        rooms.findOne({
            name: name,
        }).populate('messages')
            .exec(function (err, room) {
                let result = '';
                if (!room) {
                    console.log("Chat does not exist");
                    throw err;
                }
                else {

                    room.messages.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
                        result += '<dt>' + item.sendBy + '</dt>';
                        result += '<dd>' + item.text + '</dd>';
                    });
                }
                callback(result)
            });
    },
```

Why do I get

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendBy' of undefined`?

I tried `.populate('rooms.messages')`, `.populate({path: 'rooms.messages', model:'Messages')` and another variants, but it still doesn't work. Help me, please!

Comment: Did you console.log(room) before doing that forEach function to make sure the fields actually exist?

Comment: `'sendBy' of undefined` means that `item` is undefined within your `forEach` loop. If you get inside the `forEach` loop, it means there is an array to iterate, so this part works : `room.messages` is an array. However, from my experience, I'm always super suspiscious about what kind of stuff Mongoose produces. Immutable objects, data that looks like JSON but isn't, invisible keys or methods, you name it. Try chaining `.lean()` before `.exec()`, so you get raw data and not a Mongoose weirdo. Then `console.log()` your stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Room Schema, you're defining the messages as an object with type of Array of ObjectId, while it should be an array of elements, each element is of type ObjectId, messages should be an array of ObjectIds, and users as well

```
const RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true,
    },

    messages: [{ // note here messages is an array
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Messages',
        required: true,
    }],
    users: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: true,
    }],


});

const Room = mongoose.model('Rooms', RoomSchema);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! It does

Answer (score 0):

1. sendBy should be of type ObjectId

const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    sendBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    }

});

const Messages = mongoose.model('Messages', MessageSchema);

2. ref should be in lowercase.

   ref: 'Users', should be changed to ref:'users'

Similarly at all other `ref`s